# SQL Count of Instances of Date in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

So I've got a table of data in the link below (an excel spreadsheet in a zip file):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4mYzBk2sry_eDg5NVhTcmtXTTg/view?usp=sharing

It has been sorted and ordered as 'Date Issued - Oldest to Most Recent'.

What I'm after is a solution that gives me a count of instances an issue was made in a month for the Financial Year (01/07/2015 to 30/06/2016).

For instance, referring to the data, July 2015 had 13 issues for that month, August 2015 had 16 issues, September 2015 had 9 issues, etc.

I've created the code below to generate the data provided in the spreadsheet:

```
SELECT tblCustomerNames_1.CustomerName AS [Issued To], tblCustomerNames.CustomerName AS [Issued By], tblIssueSheets.DateIssued AS [Date Issued], Count(tblMarkHistory.MarkHistoryID) AS [Marks Issued]
FROM (tblCustomerNames AS tblCustomerNames_1 INNER JOIN (tblIssueSheets INNER JOIN tblCustomerNames ON tblIssueSheets.IssuedBy = tblCustomerNames.CustomerID) ON tblCustomerNames_1.CustomerID = tblIssueSheets.CustomerID) INNER JOIN tblMarkHistory ON tblIssueSheets.IssueID = tblMarkHistory.IssueID
WHERE (((tblIssueSheets.DateIssued)>=[DateFrom] And (tblIssueSheets.DateIssued)<[DateTo]) AND ((tblCustomerNames.CustomerID)=2447))
GROUP BY tblCustomerNames_1.CustomerName, tblCustomerNames.CustomerName, tblIssueSheets.DateIssued
ORDER BY tblCustomerNames_1.CustomerName;
```

Please note that data has been deliberately left out as I figured the information I've provided thus far is more important to what is needed. If it isn't sufficient, let me know and I'll provide the rest of the data.

A result table of the totals of Date Issued by month and year is what I'm after.

I'm not sure how to go about this at all. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your saved query as source, it could be:

```
Select 
    Month([Date Issued]) As [Month],
    Count(*) As Issues
From
    YourQuery
Where
    [Date Issued] Between #2015/07/01# And #2016/06/30#
Group By
    Month([Date Issued])
Order By
    Year([Date Issued]),
    Month([Date Issued])
```

If Month# should follow the financial year, use a generic function to offset the dates from the calendar year:

```
Public Function DateFinancial( _
  ByVal datDate As Date) _
  As Date

  ' Number of months from start of calendar year to start of financial year.
  Const clngMonthOffset As Long = 6

  Dim datFinancial      As Date

  datFinancial = DateAdd("m", -clngMonthOffset, datDate)

  DateFinancial = datFinancial

End Function
```

Comment: Is this a subquery? If so, how would I go about putting this code together with what I have so far in an Access query? Or would this be a separate query? I'm completely noob at this and just trying to build up some knowledge. :P I'm happy to look at any solution really and see the logic behind it.

Comment: The first is a query using your existing query as source. The second is a function - copy and paste into a new module. But why not bing/google for a tutorial in Access and VBA.